# Animating UINavigationBarAppearance during scroll iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I am trying to animate the new navigation bar appearance iOS 13 standard in one of my view controllers, specifically the `backgroundEffect` property. My goal is to have it appear normal and when the user scrolls down, the blur effect animates in.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.adjustedContentInset.top + scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if offset > 10  {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .clear
        appearance.backgroundEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
        appearance.shadowColor = .clear
        navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
    } else {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.backgroundColor = .clear
        appearance.backgroundEffect = nil
        appearance.shadowColor = .clear
        navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance
    }
}
```

It seems like I have to reset the entire navigation appearance instead of just setting the backgroundEffect. I have tried wrapping the appearance in a `UIView.animate()`, but it doesn't seem to work with that.

Comment: cant you reset it o other controller ?